# Ubuntu isn't playing music or videos, no sound or visuals

Tags: sound

Ubuntu isn't playing music or videos, no sound or visuals. I have no sound or video playing. It's playing ogg. None of the things that worked in windows is working here.

Comment: @Pradeeper it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be more specific please? If you try to play propitiatory formats like mp3, mp4, etc. you'd better install *ubuntu-restricted-addons* and *ubuntu-restricted-extras*. 
Issue following command in a terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-addons ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Or install the same using Ubuntu Software Center.